# Cloudformation with role chaining (by assuming additional roles) not able to GetSecretValue in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager, aws-iam-policy, aws-roles

Consider `central_secrets_account` with AWS account id XXXXXXXXXXXX that holds secrets that need to be shared with a `blue_green_account` YYYYYYYYYYYYY. I wish to create a cloudformation stack in `blue_green_account` that will access a secret in `central_secrets_account`.

My method is based on `sts:AssumeRole` chaining as follows. I have created a `blue_green_role` in `blue_green_account` that can be assumed by the local cloudformation service. The `blue_green_role` **trust policy** is

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
   ]
}
```

and its **permissions policy** is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/cross-account-read-secret-role"
        }
    ]
}
```

which allows it to assume a secret-reading role that resides in the `central_secrets_account`.

Similarly, the `cross-account-read-secret-role` in `central_secrets_account` has a **trust policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYYYYYYY:role/blue_green_role",
                    "arn:aws:sts::YYYYYYYYYYYY:assumed-role/blue_green_role/AWSCloudFormation"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

and its **permissions policy** (which is loose, just get this going) is

```
    {
        "Action": [
            "secretsmanager:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
```

However, when I spin up the stack in the `blue_green_account` which has a dynamic reference  `{{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:secret:secret_name_zzzzzz}}` in the cloudformation template, I get the following error

```
User: arn:aws:sts::YYYYYYYYYYYYYY:assumed-role/blue_green_role/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:secret:secret_name_zzzzzz because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action
```

I've tried many different adjustments to get this to work, but to no avail. There is another KMS permissions method but I feel the role assuming method is more simple for our use case.

Comment: Its not clear what you are doing. What exactly `${blue_green_account_id}` is supposed to be? An input parameter of your template?

Comment: It's just the 12 digit AWS account number for the `blue_green_account`. I used variable notation to show it's association with the account. In reality this is not a variable of course.

Comment: @Marcin - I've removed variable notation to make it clear.

Comment: The error message indicates that whatever role CloudFormation runs under does not have permission to invoke `GetSecretValue`. You haven't shown anything other than trust policies, so we have no idea whether the role grants this. Cross-account access requires two things: the resource must grant permission to the prinicpal, _and_ the principal must have permissions to access the resource.

Comment: @kdgregory - I've shown a trust policy and a permission policy for both the `blue_green_role` and  `cross-account-read-secret-role`.

Comment: This is a case where simply showing the entire role would have avoided confusion. It appears that you're expecting CloudFomation to know that it has to assume a role in `central_secrets_account`, and give it permission to do so. But (unless they've changed something _very_ recently) it has no way to know that it needs to assume that role.

Comment: When I said that "the principal must have permissions," I meant adding an `ALLOW GetSecretValue` to `blue_green_role`.

Comment: @kdgregory I added the `ALLOW` as you suggested, but to no avail. On your other point: cloudformation readily assumes `blue_green_role` without being told explicitly, but as you said, it doesn't know how to assume `cross-account-read-secret-role` while it is assuming `blue_green_role`...

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear/assumed you understood the difference between a _resource-based_ policy and an _identity-based_ policy. The secret has the former, CloudFormation has the latter.

Comment: I recommend reading about those two policy types in the IAM manual, try it out using the CLI from account B, and if you still don't have it working, then edit the question and show _everything_ that you're doing, not just selected pieces.

Comment: @kdgregory I went ahead with a resource policy on the secret and a custom KMS key-pair (for encrypting/decrypting the secret) which also has a key policy. Both the resource policy and key policy allow the various secretsmanger and external account roles (principals) to secretsmanager:GetSecretValue and kms:decrypt. This is a different method to the sts:AssumeRole approach (which I couldn't get working).